# Get data out of block iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

So,here a simple method with a block

```
    -(void)getPointsInRange:(double)radius nearByPoint:(SGPoint *)nearByPoint
{
    SGStorageQuery *query = [SGStorageQuery queryWithPoint:nearByPoint layer:SimpleGeoMainLayerName];

    [query setRadius:radius];
    [mainClient retain];
    [mainClient getRecordsForQuery:query
                      callback:[SGCallback callbackWithSuccessBlock:
                                ^(id response) {
                                    // you've got records!
                                    // to create an array of SGStoredRecord objects...

                                    NSArray *records = [NSArray arrayWithSGCollection:response  type:SGCollectionTypeRecords];
                                    NSLog(@"records received:%i",[records count]);

                                    [self arrayOfPointsReceived:records];
                                } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                    // handle failure
                                    NSLog(@"getPointsInRange error:%@",[error description]);
                                }]];


}
```

the method connects to some SDK and returns an NSArray with results.
i want to find a way that the getPointsInRange method will return the NSArray.
so its signature will be  `-(NSArray*)getPointsInRange...`
I can do it simply with delegate, but  i'd like to do it all within one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to keep your cake and eat it, too. Or have a method that calls asynchronous code and at the same time returns the results synchronously. You can turn the method into a synchronous one, if that’s what you want:

```
- (void) computeSomethingAndReturnSynchronously
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self doSomeAsynchronousOperationWithCompletion:^{
        // take the call results here
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(semaphore);
}
```

This will run the asynchronous code and then block the execution until the results from the async call are available. Does that help? (I should add that I would much rather keep the code asynchronous and return the `NSArray` in another completion block.)

Comment: GCD savvy semaphores? handy! so what happens when dispatch_semaphore_wait is called on a serial dispatch_queue? I guess it'll deschedule but remain blocked (cos otherwise it wouldn't be serial).

Comment: Yes, the queue will be blocked until the semaphore signals. This means you can easily get into a deadlock, which is why I would prefer to return the results with a regular completion block, asynchronously.